# Xamarin.forms NavigationBar Title set text color for IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, navbar

i'm working on xamarin.forms app and i want to change my Title color . I added for android and work fine , but for IOS don't know how to change. I added status bar design

```
        public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
 
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
            {
                // If VS has updated to the latest version , you can use StatusBarManager , else use the first line code
                // UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame);
                UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
                statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor(); 
                statusBar.TintColor= Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor();    
                
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
            }
            else
            {
                UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
                if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
                {
                    statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor(); 
                    statusBar.TintColor= Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor();
                }
            }
            base.OnActivated(uiApplication);
        }
```

and it's ok for status bar, Navbar design:

```
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor();
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = Color.White.ToUIColor();
```

but Title color is `Black`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try to set `UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
{
    ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
};`

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT thank you . I first wrote             UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes.ForegroundColor = Color.White.ToUIColor();  and get NullObject Exception. Now work's fine

Comment: I will post it an answer , could you accept it ? Which will help more people :)

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here **TintColor** attribute change the background color of the navigation bar

**BarTintColor** attribute affect to the color of the

- back indicator image
- button titles
- button images

So in your case , set the **TextColor** of title you could invoke the following code .

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
{
    ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
};
```